# How to stop a block of code from being parsed?

Tags: luatex, parsing

I would like to pass some latex code to lua directly without it being parsed:

```
\directlua{
    PrintPrettyLatexCode("LATEX CODE GOES HERE!")
}
```

BUT latex tries to parse the "LATEX CODE GOES HERE!". I want it to all be treated purely as a string so that the PrintPrettyLatexCode function see's it as a string.

Slashes will need to be double slashed though. I think all that is needed is to parse the code block and make all slashes double before latex parses it(that way macros like `\mymacro` end up becoming `\\mymacro` and I think latex will then not try to expand it)

Maybe something like

```
\directlua{
    PrintPrettyLatexCode(\MakeDoubleSlashes{"LATEX CODE GOES HERE!"})
}
```

will work if `\MakeDoubleSlashes` exist?

Answer (score 5):

LuaTeX provides `\luaescapestring` for escaping characters in Lua strings:

```
\directlua{
  PrintPrettyLatexCode("\luaescapestring\expandafter{\detokenize{LATEX CODE GOES HERE!}}")
}
```

**Addition**

The following defines an environment `PrettyPrintLatexCode`:

1. The environment contents is written to a temporary file using package `filecontents`.
2. The file contents is stored in a macro by `\CatchFileEdef` of package `catchfile`.
   All characters are read verbatim by using a catcode table, where all slots are set to catcode 12 (`other`) and the line ends are read as byte `0x10` (`\n`).
3. The data are passed via `\luatexluaescapestring` (that is `\luaescapestring` in `LuaLaTeX`) to the function `PrettyPrintLatexCode`.

The full example:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\RequirePackage{catchfile}
\RequirePackage{luacode}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\PrettyPrint@FileName}{test.file}
\newenvironment*{PrettyPrintLatexCode}{%
  \csname filecontents*\endcsname{\PrettyPrint@FileName}%
}{%
  \csname endfilecontents*\endcsname
  \CatchFileEdef{\PrettyPrint@FileData}{\PrettyPrint@FileName}{%
    \PrettyPrint@CatchSetup
  }%
  \luadirect{%
    PrettyPrintLatexCode("\luatexluaescapestring{\PrettyPrint@FileData}")%
  }%
}
\begingroup
  \lccode`\~=13 %
  \lccode`\9=10 %
\lowercase{\endgroup
  \def\PrettyPrint@CatchSetup{%
    \luatexcatcodetable\CatcodeTableOther
    \endlinechar=13 %
    \catcode13=\active
    \def~{9}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

% Provide a dummy definition for PrettyPrintLatexCode
\luadirect{%
function PrettyPrintLatexCode(str)
  texio.write_nl(
    "*****************************",
    str,
    "*****************************",
    ""
  )
end}

\begin{PrettyPrintLatexCode}
\section{Hello World}

Some text with "double" and 'single' quotes.
  and unmatched (parentheses].

Umlauts: äöüß
\end{PrettyPrintLatexCode}

\stop
```

Result of the dummy `PrettyPrintLatexCode` in the terminal/log file:

```
*****************************
\section{Hello World}

Some text with "double" and 'single' quotes.
  and unmatched (parentheses].

Umlauts: äöüß
*****************************
```

Comment: It should be noted that this adds spaces after every control word.

Comment: While it does work it also adds `\par` on new lines(instead of using a `\n`). So it works but changes the code which is not good.

Answer (score 2):

You could load the `luacode` package and use `\luaexec` instead of `\directlua`:

```
\luaexec{
    PrintPrettyLatexCode(\MakeDoubleSlashes{"LATEX CODE GOES HERE!"})
}
```

(This assumes, of course, that `PrintPrettyLatexCode` is a valid `lua` function and `` `MakeDoubleSlashes `` is a valid TeX macro.) You will still need to prefix a backslash to `#` and `%` characters; however, the `~` (tilde) and `\\` (double backslash) characters needn't be escaped. To typeset a single backslash, you'll need to use `\string\`.

Comment: I do not think this will work in any way in solving my original problem? The latex code will have an issue in that stuff like `"\par"` will have `\p` interpreted as an escape code. luaexec only solves half the problem of modifying the cat codes but not fixing up lua "strings".

Comment: @AbstractDissonance: Thanks for clarifying your actual needs -- your initial posting didn't indicate (at least to me...) that the argument of `\MakeDoubleSlashes` might contain formatting-related code that needs to be parsed by LaTeX; indeed, the posting's title has something about keeping a block of code from being parsed. Please consider posting a meaningful MWE (minimum working example) of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @AbstractDissonance - Why the sarcasm (or am I misunderstanding your comment as well)? Your question has the term "stop a block of code from being parsed" in the title, and that's what I was working with. Quite evidently I didn't understand your objective -- but expressing that thought in no way implies that it was *your* fault I didn't understand your question.